# "Server Busy" error each time I log on to Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

I see this message whenever I log on to Windows:

[image: Server Busy: This action cannot be completed because the other program is busy. Choose 'Switch To' to activate the busy program and correct the problem. "Switch To..." | "Retry"]

What's wrong? Why does it appears? What should I do about it?

Additional Details: I use Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit OS.

Comment: Which operating system? You tagged the question "server", but you just say it's "Windows". There are several versions of Windows. Try tagging questions as thoroughly as possible since that gets the "right" people watching the question.

Comment: It also helps to make your question title more descriptive. And note that many people rely on alt text for images. So please remember to describe your image in your alt text. It helps search engines, and it also helps people who are using text-only browsers or screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first check your event log to see if the error is logged, and if so, by what program. If not, then the standard procedure for debugging a startup error is to restart your computer with the minimum number of programs and services to determine which program/service is causing the error. From there, it'll be easier to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1-on desktop,hit "alt+ctrl+del"
2-choose task manager
3-choose process bar
4-"end task" the applications one by one which you have installed
5-when the culprit application is closed,the message would disappear instantly
6- uninstall or prevent the culprit program to run during start up.

enjoy-Babak

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on a Windows 7 computer. Eventually, I found that the apple products software were stuck trying to update.  Once I manually ran the Apple update program, the server busy error stopped. (It updates iCLOUD, iTunes, etc.)

A long time ago I had this same problem caused by an Adobe update that would not complete.

Hope this helps someone resolve this issue.